# Wordpress 3.6: Page under category

Tags: php, wordpress

**The Problem:**
My menu bar contains a set of categories. Posts automatically align. A new Plugin is based on Pages. The Page e.g. 'p1' is always on the main site.

**The Idea:**
Create a template that assigns a page to a specific category e.g. 'p1' -> 'c1'. I found a piece of code

```
<?php if (is_category('c1')) : ?>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to tell the program:

```
if (is_category('c1')) :  show page / vice versa?>
```

***How do I do that?***

Answer (score 0):

You will want a naming standard between pages and categories. Once that is done you can do the following (or something like it):

```
<?php if(is_category('c1)) : ?>
<?php query_posts('category_name=c1&order=asc');
if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <div class="pageWrapper">
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>No content was found</p>
<?php 
     endif; 
wp_reset_query();//If writing your own queries, always a good idea to reset it. ?>
```